# Noun for people who are religious (abrahamic) yet believes in luck, astrology, and other superstition

Tags: nouns

I came a cross a word (which I find easily forgettable) that describes people who are very religious (mostly pertaining to christians) yet hypocritically believes in superstitions like Luck, Feng Shui, Astrology and other related superstition.

I am not sure if this is a tip-of-the-tongue moment since I've never even used that difficult word once.

I may have problems describing the word, so maybe your questions might lead us to get a better description on what we're looking for.

*I have tried Google, but the results are mostly about religious articles instead...*

Comment: Hmm, not a word I've ever used.

Comment: Where did you come across this word?

Comment: I read it in wikipedia when I was article hopping.

Comment: Well, from the perspective of the orthodox members of the religion, you might be thinking of *heresy*. Anything in the way of a "starts with" or "sounds like" might help us to help you better.

Comment: How about ["Sunday Christian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_Christian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only word that comes to mind is "syncretistic." I've heard it used it mostly in talking about countries where Christianity has been brought in by missionaries, yet the local native religions continued to flourish. The two were "syncretistically" combined into a new religion still (confusingly) called Christianity. Definitely not an everyday word!

Comment: [**Religious syncretism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_syncretism) is the exact word I'm looking for.
But with @fool4jesus' answer, I was able to find the specific word.

Comment: Our priest used to say of my aunt who believed in things like painting symbols around the drains in the basement to block evil spirits,  that she was "very spiritual".

Comment: Note to OP: **syncretism** has no connotations of *hypocrisy*. It refers only  to a mish-mash of beliefs amenable to mish-mashery.

Comment: Yes, I have used that word to described what I very vaguely could remember from the meaning after reading it a long time ago, though it wasn't the definition at all.

But I bet after finding out the word again. It will be the same way I would remember it... Stemming from: religion > superstitious practice > hypocrisy

I hope you get where I came from.